# How to nondimensionalize a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

> A body of mass $m$ is thrown upwards in a vertical direction from the
>   earth's surface with a velocity $v$. The air resistance is supposed to
>   be taken into account by Stoke's law $F_R= - cv$ for the flow
>   resistance in viscous fluids, which is reasonable for small
>   velocities. Here $c$ is a coefficient depending on the shape and size
>   of the body. The motion is supposed to depend on the mass $m$, the
>   velocity $v$, the gravitaional acceleration $g$ and the friction
>   coefficient $c$ with dimension $[c]= \frac{M}{T}$.
>
> The initial value problem for the height is assumed to take the form
>   $$ mx''+cx'=-mg$$
>
> $$x(0)=0$$
>
> $$x'(0)=v$$
>   Non dimensionalize the differential equation.

First I rewrote it to
$$ x'' = -g-\frac{c}{m} x'$$
$$x(0)=0$$
$$x'(0)=v$$

Than I wrote down the fundamental dimensions, mass $M$, time $T$ and height $H$.
After that I determined the dimensions of the involved quantities
$[x] = H$

$[g]=\frac{H}{T^2}$

$[v]=\frac{H}{T}$

$[c]=\frac{M}{T}$

$[m]=M$

$[t]= T$

I thought to nondimensionalize  I to define $\tau = \frac{t}{\bar{t}}$, $y=\frac{x}{\bar{x}}$ and  $z= \frac{m}{\bar{m}}$ where $\bar{t},\bar{x} and \bar{m}$ are characteristic quantities.

Now I wanted to do a change of variables, and write $x''$ as $y''(\tau)$,but that is where it went wrong.

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}(\bar{x}\frac{dy}{dt}) = \bar{x}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0$$

I'm pretty new to this and I tried to look up similar problems and try the methods they used, but I just don't know what to do. Any nod in the right direction is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling

$$
\cases{
\tau = \frac{t}{t_o}\\
\eta = \frac{x}{x_o}
}
$$

we have

$$
\frac{d^n}{dt^n} = \frac{1}{t_o^n}\frac{d^n}{d\tau^n}
$$

and after substitution

$$
m\frac{x_o}{t_o^2}\eta''+ c\frac{x_o}{t_o}\eta' + m g = 0
$$

or

$$
\eta'' + \frac{c t_o}{m}\eta'+\frac{t_o^2 g}{x_o} = 0
$$

now determining $x_o,t_o$ such that

$$
\cases{
\frac{c t_o}{m} = 1\\
\frac{t_o^2 g}{x_o} = 1
}
$$

we have

$$
t_o = \frac mc,\ \ \ x_o = \frac{m^2}{c^2}g
$$

and consequently

$$
\eta''+\eta'+1=0
$$
etc.